# How to keep a shape square in the middle of a changing viewport

Tags: geometry

Hello I have a problem with a shape that needs to remain as a square whatever a viewport is like, see this image

[image: see this image]

- I'm trying to calculate the height of both red zones, `sumOfRedHeights`
- By knowing this sumOfRedHeights value, I'll be able to make the blue shape a SQUARE at any viewport size.
- The blue square is always 40% of the viewport width.
- At some point `sumOfRedHeights` will be 0 or negative, we can ignore this. I only need the calculation for values above 0.

I'm able to know the viewportHeight, the viewportWidth and the viewportAspectRatio at any given size.
I think it's rather simple but my brain is freezing hard :(

*(It's for web, I know I can use things like aspect-ratio in CSS but I can't here, it will be done via Javascript)*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $w$ denote the viewport width, $h$ the viewport height, $s$ the sum of the heights of the pink zones and $p=0.4$ the percentage of the width that the square should fill. Then $s = h - p w$.

Comment: Legend! Super simple, thank you.